# Type text in RadEditor using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, rad, hidden-field, radeditor

I am automating a webpage using **selenium**.

My Problem is **selenium** is unable to type the text in **hidden fields**. I used

```
selenium.type("xpath of hidden field","some text");
```

But it is not working. It's not giving any error, but not typing anything into that hidden field.

**Example: Typing text into Gmail's body field(in composing mail).** `this is the exact example of my issue`

This is Rad Editor. So code is something like this(here the text is saving inside `iframe-->html-->body`)

```
<iframe id="iframe1">
<html>
<body> This is some text </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

[image: Field where i am trying to add text]

Answer (score 1):

There's just no way you'll force Selenium to type into a hidden element.

Would this work? It uses Javascript's [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate) to find the element by XPath and then types directly into the found element's `value`.

```
selenium.GetEval(
        "var xpath = '//XPath/to/your/element';" +
        "var text = 'some text to input into the element'" +
        "var elem = window.document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);" +
        "elem.singleNodeValue.value = text;" );
```

If not, try to run it in FireBug and post the result (or error) here.

---

The next thing to try would be to try to make the element visible...

---

### EDIT - the above won't work

You have like all the problems in one place :)

1. An `iframe`. You must [select it](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_SelectFrame.htm) before trying to interact with anything inside.
2. If the `iframe` loads anything from a different domain, then the [Same origin policy](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#the-same-origin-policy) for JavaScript kicks in. And since Selenium RC is written in pure JavaScript, it can't do anything. You can either switch to `WebDriver` which doesn't suffer from this, or try to reopen the browser on the internal address of the `iframe`. Might not work, though.
3. The `body` tag in the `iframe` is `contenteditable` which is a problem [solved by `WebDriver`](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_type_into_a_contentEditable_iframe?). Selenium RC should be able to `type()` into it just as well.
4. An invisible `textarea`. That's your last problem. If you really needed to write into it (there's the editable `body`), you you'll have to use JavaScript, because Selenium RC refuses to work with invisible elements.

Comment: In C#, it's [`GetEval()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_GetEval.htm), obviously.

Comment: That's a JS limitation and security policy, I can't be sure about the exact reason. Shame. You can try making the element visible, but you'll most likely bump into the same problem. This way will be a no-go. I doubt there's anything you can do now.

Comment: Hi Slanec. i have added a snap shot of my field where am trying to add the text. Please look at it once.here hidden field means it's just like **Gmail's** body field. even it is not recording anything in **selenium IDE**

Comment: The Gmail's body field is hidden in an `iframe`! That's the reason of the security exception - [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You must [select the frame](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_SelectFrame.htm) before interacting with it with Selenium RC. [You may need](http://automationtricks.blogspot.cz/2010/09/how-to-write-in-iframe-in-selenium.html) [to overcome the `contenteditable` issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_type_into_a_contentEditable_iframe?), too.

Comment: [It might even not work at all.](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Oh. That's not contenteditable then, fine. One problem out of four solved :).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13051/discussion-between-rannu-and-slanec)

Comment: Hi Slanec. Thank you very much for your suggestions and help. Atlast i solved it :-)) :-)) (I will post the answer)

Answer (score 0):

As this is a **RadEditor** the text is going inside `iframe-->html-->body` (**This is in my case**. It may be different for different Editors)

So in order to write text, first we need to select the **iframe**. And then we have to enter the text. This can be done as

```
selenium.SelectFrame("xpath_of_iframe"); //Selecting the iframe
selenium.Type("//html/body","Thank you"); //Inserting the text
```

So now the code changes to

```
<iframe id="iframe1">
<html>
<body> Thank you </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Thank you.